# How to stop the HTTP serving function after one request

Tags: http, go, server, request

To authenticate a user with a 3rd party service I need to listen and wait on a localport so I get a token by that service.

How is it possible to exit a server in go after one request?

As far as I'm aware it's only possible with listenAndServer to that forever, but on for just one single request

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server and https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Close

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mkopriva I was able to do it.

It's actually pretty simple, just create a server object manually and then call s.Close() in your handle function

```
s := &http.Server{
    Addr: "localhost:8085",
}
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    //do sth
    s.Close()
})
s.ListenAndServe()
//do sth else
```

Comment: Do note that, if you have other servers run by the same program, and they too use the DefaultServeMux, you might get unnecessary conflict for the `"/"` path. So you may want to use the Server's Handler field instead. Something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/KR46siACwmo

Comment: Don't rely on this. It's very racy.

Comment: @Flimzy I'm currently single threaded and it is supposed to just listen on localhost, but I'll keep that in mind

Comment: @Jona: You're not single-threaded, as `ListenAndServe` is inherently multi-threaded (well, it uses concurrency, which translates to multi-threaded by default if you have more than one CPU). But listening just on localhost helps.

Comment: What I would suggest instead, regardless of localhost or not, is to wait until you know you've received the HTTP request you're expecting, then shut down. And in case you receive other requests in the meantime, queue them, and just process them on a FIFO basis. This will work in any environment.

Comment: @Flimzy With single threaded I meant everything in my program will wait until the HandleFunc get's called, so I think there shouldn't be too much of racing issues. And, I think thats important, this is not server code but client code. That's the reason why I don't want to wait a constant amount of time before closing the server, I'm waiting for user input here.

Comment: `ListenAndServe` makes it server code, by definition. :) And what happens if something other than _your_ code makes a connection to that server?

Comment: @Flimzy Sure, you're right :-D I meant it is supposed to run directly on the users system, not as a productive server environment. If something else will make a connection it's fine if it breaks, since this route handles user authentication and I suppose something is going really wrong if another app tries to connect to that route.

Comment: @Flimzy to not flood the comment section to much: I think currently it is a better fit for my application to just listen for one request because the application is still quite simple and I got the feeling that the user is more aware of what's happening if it will fail when another application tries to connect to it, which is not supposed to happen.
However, I appreciate your input and since the architecture might change in the future and I will keep in mind to rethink that pattern.